# updating the values in database from datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i want to create a for loop in which i want to write a query which updates the the value of each row in database. the rows are present in the datagridview as well as in the database. the aim is when the changes are made in datagridview so using a button the change are also applied in the database table too. in each row the barcode and its quantity is different. if the changes are made in all the rows in datagridview so it is also to be applied in database using button and also please help with the parameters.

here is the query which should be considered in the for loop:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("update prod_info set item_quantity=@qty where barcode=@barcode ", con);
```

consider barcode as column1 and item_quantity as column2.

so far to create a for loop i have tried this but getting error in the for loops:

```
for (int i = 0; dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)  //getting error here
            {
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("update prod_info set item_quantity=@qty where barcode=@barcode ", con);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? One possibility would be to bind the DataGridView to a DataTable and use [the SqlCommandBuilder helper class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz.aspx) that generates the insert/select/update/delete command for you, once when binded to the UI element, so changes to the Database are made "automatically".

Comment: well i want to make changes to the database by using button. i mean when everything is confirmed in datagridview then using the button changes are to be made

Comment: this is the code i have tried so far and i am getting error in the for loops:

for (int i = 0; dataGridView2.Rows.count; i++)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("update prod_info set item_quantity=@qty where barcode=@barcode ", con);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            }

Comment: @pasty i have edited the main question you can see the changes there

Comment: @HaiderKhattak what kind of error did you receive? your loop does nothing, just creates a command, adds some parameters and does nothing.

Comment: @KingKing....thats the point...the problem is i cant create a loop correctly...

Answer (score 0):

you should call **cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();** in your loop ... otherwise no sql commands will be executed

to get a better solution you should move to creation of cmd2 before the loop. also add the parameters there (without assigning values) ... inside the loop just assign the values and call ExecuteNonQuery.

maybe the best solution would be to use databinding and a SqlDataAdapter with assigned UpdateCommand.

just saw that there probably is an error in your code ... you use the value from **Cell[1]** for **both** of your parameters ...

example:
first create a DataTable ... **var dt = new DataTable();**

then add the columns you want in your grid to the DataTable ... **dt.Columns.Add("xyz");**

then attach the DataTable to your grid: **dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;**

now you should be able to edit the contents of column "xyz". to write the values to the database you create a SqlDataAdapter ... **var adp = new SqlDataAdapter();**

then set **adp.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(...)** and **adp.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(...)**

now you can call **adp.Update();** and all the values from your grid are written to db ... for newly added rows the InsertCommand is invoked and for edited rows the UpdateCommand is invoked.

Comment: actually i want to update the value of cell[1] into the database...Rows[i] is just defined to locate the row and update the quantity against the barcode...
can you please give an example of databinding...???